# Open source advertising network app/framework/cms

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system, ads

I'm tired of advertising networks (except some good) who ban me even not my fault. I now maybe will run out of money to pay the server cost. So I'm going to build my own advertising network.

Im looking for good open source advertising network app/framework/cms in any language, no matter they function for CPM or CPC.

I've found some in Github, but I dont have experience with it.

I want to make my own "Adsense". something like that where people can register, login and manage their own ads.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [openX](http://www.openx.org/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to make my own "Adsense". something like that where people can register, login and manage their own ads.